# python pandas if 1 in column A, use value of column B in same row

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, dataframe

I have two columns, `BinaryCol` which is, as you may have guessed, 0s and 1s, and `OnsetTime` which ranges from 0 to 294. I want to make a new column which will contain the value of `OnsetTime` only for the rows where `BinaryCol` = 1

I currently have this:

```
df['Test'] = df['BinaryCol'].apply(lambda row: ['OnsetTime'] if row['BinaryCol'] > 0 else 0, axis=1)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do product of the two columns.

```
df['Test'] = df['OnsetTime'] * df['BinaryCol']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy`'s `where`:

```
df['Test'] = np.where(df['BinaryCol'], df['OnsetTime'], np.NaN)
```

`df['BinaryCol']` is the condition, `df['OnsetTime']` is the value if the condition is `True`, and `np.NaN` the value if the condition is `False`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply your function to a data frame, not a series

```
    df['Test'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row['OnsetTime'] if row['BinaryCol'] == 1 else 0), axis = 1)
```